# Requisição HTML EM XML

Tags: html, xml

Olá! Estou tentando fazer uma requisição de um software que seta o caminho de uma imagem via XML.
a imagem é pega dentro da pasta do projeto!
teria como eu pegar via link de uma pagina da web?

```
                    <Control name="loadingFGImage"  mouse="false" bkimage="file=&apos;
                        img/simagem.jpg&apos;
                         corner=&apos;
                         4,4,4,4&apos;
                         mask=&apos;
                         0xffff00ff&apos;
                         " visible="true" />
```

Comment: Olá Higor. É importante você [edit] e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema** (essa é a parte mais importante), ou seja, um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. Não delete e nem recrie a pergunta, apenas edite e aguarde o processo de reabertura. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.